# How to Hide/Open Angular Material Dropdown

Tags: angular

I'm trying to hide/open the angular material dropdown menu.

treps.html

```
<mat-form-field>
          <mat-select  #color formControlName="colors">
            <mat-option value=''></mat-option>
            <mat-option [value]="color" *ngFor="let color of colors"> {{color}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
<mat-form-field>

<button (click)="onClick()">Hide/Open</button>
```

treps.ts

```
  @ViewChild('color') color

  onClick() {
   this.color.hide()   // Error appears in the console,stating hide is not a function
 }
```

I tried checking the all properties but couldn't hide the dropdown.

Comment: You can use *ngIf or style to hide

Comment: @Nikhil Walvekar, On button click I need to hide. So any idea ?

Comment: Can you try specifying the Class you are trying to access with @ViewChild like so: `<mat-select #color="matSelect" formControlName="colors">` and then in the controller `@ViewChild('color') color: MatSelect`

Comment: @Shivaay here is an example https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_ng-if

Answer (score 0):

to hide you need to add *ngIf attribute to your mat-select

this will hide mat-select on a particular condition

to make this happen you need to add

```
<mat-form-field>
          <mat-select  #color formControlName="colors" *ngIf="hideDropdown">
            <mat-option value=''></mat-option>
            <mat-option [value]="color" *ngFor="let color of colors"> {{color}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
<mat-form-field>

<button (click)="onClick()">Hide/Open</button>
```

in ts file

```
 hideDropdown : bollean = true;
    onClick() {
      //you can perform your logic to hide in this function
       this.hideDropdown =false   // Error appears in the console,stating hide is not a function
     }
```

Comment: I believe what he wants to hide is the actual dropdown menu, not the whole mat-select element.

Comment: can you please try me explaining more what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

In general, angular approach is using `*ngIf` attribute.
but there are some other approaches.

**1. Attribute binding:**

```html
<mat-form-field [attr.hidden]="isHidden">
          <mat-select formControlName="colors">
            <mat-option value=''></mat-option>
            <mat-option [value]="color" *ngFor="let color of colors"> {{color}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
<mat-form-field>

<button (click)="isHidden= !isHidden">Hide/Open</button>
```

**2. ngClass**:

Using this aprocah requires corresponding `shown : {display : none}`
 css class.

```html
<mat-form-field [ngClass]="{'shown': isShown}>
          <mat-select formControlName="colors">
            <mat-option value=''></mat-option>
            <mat-option [value]="color" *ngFor="let color of colors"> {{color}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
<mat-form-field>

<button (click)="isShown = !isShown">Hide/Open</button>
```

Comment: This will hide entire field, In my case dropdown need to be hidden

Answer (score 0):

You might be just be missing the type of the attribute you want to obtain with ViewChild. Try this:

```
<mat-form-field>
      <mat-select  #color="matSelect" formControlName="colors">
        <mat-option value=''></mat-option>
        <mat-option [value]="color" *ngFor="let color of colors"> {{color}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
<mat-form-field>

<button (click)="onClick()">Hide/Open</button>
```

And then in your controller:

```
@ViewChild('color') color: MatSelect;

onClick() {
  this.color.hide()   // Error appears in the console,stating hide is not a function
}
```

Here you have an example. Excuse the poor styling, I hope you get the point from there: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mkdakz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

After numerous attempts, I figured out :

treps.html

```
<mat-form-field>
          <mat-select  #color formControlName="colors">
            <mat-option value=''></mat-option>
            <mat-option [value]="color" *ngFor="let color of colors"> {{color}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
<mat-form-field>

<button (click)="onClick()">Hide/Open</button>
```

treps.ts

```
 @ViewChild('color') color : MatSelect

  onClick() {
   this.color.close()   // Changed from hide() to close()
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-Container and ngIf together to achieve this

```
<ng-container *ngIf="IsShowHide">
<mat-form-field>
      <mat-select  #color formControlName="colors">
        <mat-option value=''></mat-option>
        <mat-option [value]="color" *ngFor="let color of colors"> {{color}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
<mat-form-field>
</ng-container>

<button (click)="onClick()">Hide/Open</button>
```

in ts file

```
onClick(){
  this.IsShowHide = !this.IsShowHide;
}
```